# "If it were absent" in the following context - correct?

Tags: grammar

> "It looks not important but in fact its presence is very important
>   compared to **if it were absent**."

Is it correct to use that way? 
The meaning is to say: It's better for us to have it, than to not have it. It works?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean to say, but because "presence" is the *antonym* of "absence", it's what we would call ["circular reasoning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning).  Of course if it's important that something be there, it's better than not being there -- if it made no difference, then you would not say it was important.  In order to make this a meaningful sentence you have to add more information about what happens in the thing's absence.

Comment: Thank you. The explanation should be in this sentence or can come in the next sentence? For example: Its absence cause less benefit of money.

Comment: @andrew, your comment doesn't ask for suggest improvements to the question or ask for clarification. If you have an answer to the question, please use the answer box.

Comment: @Perplexedfolks  It could come wherever you like.  This is more about logic than it is about English, as you can have circular reasoning in *any* language, I should think.

Comment: @JamesK  the comment does not represent a sincere effort to answer the question, but instead points out a flaw in the logic that makes the question difficult to answer.  If OP fixes that flaw, I might take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to the express the idea "It is better for us to have it than to not have it", then the following is *not* good:

> It looks not important but in fact its presence is very important compared to if it were absent.

You cannot compare "presence" to an *if*-clause.  Sometimes native speakers will say things like this when they lose track of their own words:

> Having a little money is better than if you had none at all.

and the listener must give the speaker the benefit of the doubt and guess what it is that the speaker wants to say:

> Having a little money is better than having none at all.

Moreover, a comparison requires a comparative adjective, and  "very" is not a comparative.

But even if we "fix" that error and change the *if*-clause to **absence**, your sentence does not convey your desired meaning:

> It seems unimportant but in fact its presence is more important than its absence.

What that means is that we would consider its absence relatively insignificant and its presence relatively significant.

For example, if you have a screening test that rarely gives "false positives" but often gives "false negatives", and this test says that a specific antibody is present in the blood, you might say:

> With this particular blood test, the antibody's presence is more important than its absence.

However, such a statement does not imply that it is "better for us" to have that antibody in our blood than not to have it.  "More important" does not mean "better".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!^+1 Is there a way not to give up on the using of "if it were absent."?

Comment: *We wouldn't care if it were absent but its presence would be significant.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: @Perplexedfolks You asked for an example where "if it were absent" was employed.  I gave you one.